# book recommendation for martingale theory?

Tags: probability-theory, book-recommendation

I am taking courses about stochastic processes, Markov chains, martingales,(mainly on brownian motion).

My background is Electrical Engineering, where I had an introductory course about probability and statistics from a quite applied point of view. Moreover, almost all I had up to now was discrete probability theory. 
I was reading a book by rogers and williams on Ito calculus, it requires knowledge about measure theory and martingales. so i wan't to ask what book i can read so  that i can read that text smoothly. or as it uses

Comment: Have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1158640/ and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/46213/

Comment: I want to get recommendations on martingales .@saz

Comment: In your question it reads "measure theory and martingales" ... the book by Schilling (which is mentioned in the first question I linked) contains material on martingales. Further literature on martingales: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1341723/